# GODI installation error

Tags: installation, ocaml, godi

I'm running Fedora 9 x86_64 and am more or less a Linux newbie (not using it, but installing and such). The error occurs in the second stage of the bootstrap (i.e. "./bootstrap_stage2").
It does a whole lot fo stuff and then these errors start happening:

```
Fatal error: exception Out_of_memory
make[8]: *** [odoc_html.cmo] Error 2
make[8]: Leaving directory `/home/matthew/godi/build/godi/godi-ocaml/work/ocaml/ocamldoc'
make[7]: *** [ocamldoc] Error 2
make[7]: Leaving directory `/home/matthew/godi/build/godi/godi-ocaml/work/ocaml'
Error: Exec error: File /home/matthew/godi/build/godi/godi-ocaml/./../../mk/bsd.pkg.mk, line 1039: Command returned with non-zero exit code
Error: Exec error: File /home/matthew/godi/build/godi/godi-ocaml/./../../mk/bsd.pkg.mk, line 1378: Command returned with non-zero exit code
Error: Command fails with code 1: godi_console
Failure!
```

I've run it monitoring my memory and can say that I definately have not run out (using about 500 and I've got 3).
So anyone know what the issue is? I've searched the net, but the only other similar thing I found was the other thread on here (but it had a different error)

Any help would be much appreciated, because last time I installed it, it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a [known problem](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=4448) with old OCaml (<3.11) on 64-bit platforms likely triggered by heap randomization, which is enabled on Fedora.  It's been fixed so far as I know in recent releases (3.11 at least, possibly 3.10.2).  Up-to-date GODI running out of section 3.11 should work if this is the case.